# Cannot connect to Connection Manager

Tags: gazebo-1.4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I have followed the installation guide here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.4/install and installed Gazebo using the pre-compiled binaries for Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (precise). However, when I execute the following command:

```
bram@bram-progbak:~$ gazebo
```

I get the following output:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.4.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.4.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Msg Waiting for master...................................................................................................
```

And the dots go on forever. When I hit CTRL-C the following messages is displayed:
`Error [ConnectionManager.cc:89] Connection Manager is not running`

I have also tried to use the Gazebo package which is integrated with ROS but the same happens there. The following environmental variables have been defined:

```
GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345

GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models

GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/gazebo-1.4/plugins

GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-1.4:/usr/share/gazebo_models
```

Here is the tracelog when I try to run gzmaster:

```
bram@bram-progbak:~/builds/gazebo-1.4.0/build$ gdb gzmaster
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/gzmaster...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/gzmaster 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffeceb9700 (LWP 5329)]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.4.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
gazebo::Master::Init (this=0x0, _port=11345) at /home/bram/builds/gazebo-1.4.0/gazebo/Master.cc:65
65      this->connection->Listen(_port, boost::bind(&Master::OnAccept, this, _1));
(gdb) wher
#0  gazebo::Master::Init (this=0x0, _port=11345) at /home/bram/builds/gazebo-1.4.0/gazebo/Master.cc:65
#1  0x000000000040f39b in main () at /home/bram/builds/gazebo-1.4.0/gazebo/master_main.cc:58
(gdb)
```

Hope you guys can help me get the master server to run. Thanks!

Bram

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1213/cannot-connect-to-connection-manager./) by [Morloth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/196/morloth/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-02-05**:
Yes, I'm having the same problem.

**Comment by [Morloth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/196/morloth/) on 2013-02-05**:
It seems that the problem is that when I run gzmaster it segfaults. (updated original post).

**Comment by [Morloth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/196/morloth/) on 2013-02-05**:
Just installed version Gazebo 1.3 which does work. So I'm not sure what the problem is with version 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here you go, hope it helps.

```
bram@bram-progbak:~/gazebo_workspace/models/roomba$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:4d:51:ba:9d  
          inet addr:137.73.9.44  Bcast:137.73.9.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:4dff:fe51:ba9d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5160510 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:1044009 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3180319676 (3.1 GB)  TX bytes:125889629 (125.8 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fe600000-fe620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:7990940 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7990940 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6936528882 (6.9 GB)  TX bytes:6936528882 (6.9 GB)


bram@bram-progbak:~/gazebo_workspace/models/roomba$ hostname
bram-progbak

bram@bram-progbak:~/gazebo_workspace/models/roomba$ domainname
(none)

bram@bram-progbak:~/gazebo_workspace/models/roomba$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   bram-progbak

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

---

Originally posted by [Morloth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/196/morloth/) with karma: 36 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-05**:
The short-term solution is to remove "localhost" from the "::1" line. I'm working on a patch to gazebo now.

**Comment by [Morloth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/196/morloth/) on 2013-02-06**:
Great! That worked, thank you very much.